# Extract More than 3 Words After the First Word

Tags: blackberry, java-me

In the app I'm working on, I need to extract the first word from a `String` and put it into another `String` and the rest of the words in yet another `String`. I was able to extract the first word using:

```
String pString = "KOF0000094 Implementation:ListingRequest:User FO-Partner"
int spacePos3 = pString.indexOf(" ");
String pFirstWord = pString.substring(0,spacePos3);
```

Result : KOF0000094

Now I want the "Implementation:ListingRequest:User FO-Partner" to put
in another `String`.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: pString.substring(spacePos3)?

Comment: Or pString.substring(spacePos3 + 1) if you want to get rid of the space.

Comment: Is this really interesting question?

Comment: No its a simple parsing question... Try spending five minutes looking at the java String class...

Comment: @Sultan, are all the answers failed to answer you question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple string parsing... just find the first index of the first space... i.e. in a for loop...

```
if(string.charAt(i) == Characters.SPACE)
    indexOfSpace = i;
```

Then your first word will be

```
String part1 = string.substring(0,indexOfSpace);
```

and the second string will be

```
String part2 = string.substring(indexOfSpace + 1);
```

Comment: This `String part2 = string.substring(indexOfSpace + 1);` will not work because there are three spaces and not one. You need to either use `trim()` on your result or use `indexOfSpace + 3`

Comment: @MikeMeyers This is an acceptable approach.. Understand I did not write all of the code required.. This is an extremely simple parsing question.. Assuming a basic knowledge of programming.. you need to add a for loop and put a break inside of that if statement. Then the index will be the first space.. I assumed this would not be a concept that would need explaining.. I simply was showing how to find a space character in the for loop

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution with what you already have.

```
String restOfString = pString.substring(spacePos3+1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String pSecondWord = pString.substring(spacePos3 + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String whole = "KOF0000094 Implementation:ListingRequest:User FO-Partner";
String firstWord = "";  
String restOfWords = "";

int spacesIndex = whole.indexOf("   ", 0);
restOfWords = whole.substring(spacesIndex, whole.length());
restOfWords = restOfWords.trim();
firstWord = whole.substring(0, spacesIndex);
firstWord = firstWord.trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using another call to substring(). What is the index of the first character in the string you want? What is the index of the last character?

Answer (score 2):

You already have the index of the first space, which marks the end of the first word, so all you need to do is take the substring from the index immediately after that (so you don't include the space itself) to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better of using the split function
It would look something like this:

```
String pString = "KOF0000094 Implementation:ListingRequest:User FO-Partner";        
String[] parts = pString.split(" ");
String partone = parts[0];
String partwo  = parts[1] + " " +parts[2];
```

Or something similar, if there are going to be more spaces in the part following the first word you could use a loop or something similar;

Comment: Oops I'm sorry, I expected blackberry would support atleast java 5, but this is ridiculous. Well the other solutions given will work also.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>String class has a split method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)</strike>

Use that if you want to get all the words.

EDIT: as mentioned in the comments, `String.split` is not supported in BB Java.

Or this if you just want the first word and the rest of the string:

```
int index=yourstring.indexOf(" ");
String firstWord = yourstring.substring(0,index);
String rest = yourstring.substring(index+1);
```

Comment: In the example, split() will give an array with 3 strings, but the OP only wants to split it into two strings, if I read it correctly.

Comment: @Code-Guru You'd need to do some additional step to combine all elements in the array except the first into a single String, but `split()` is an option (though probably not the best).

Comment: This being BlackBerry, the full Java API isn't available anyway: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score -1):

You could use split, for instance...

```
static String pString = "KOF0000094 Implementation:ListingRequest:User FO-Partner";
    static String[] pFirstWord = pString.split(" ");

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(String word : pFirstWord) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

This returned...

```
KOF0000094

Implementation:ListingRequest:User

FO-Partner
```

So the last string would be pFirstWord[1] + pFirstWord[2]

Comment: David, this code isn't compilable on BB. BB is still Java 1.3.